# QString replace urls with links

Tags: qt4

I'm receiving messages from a socket and writing an html log of it. I need to search the messages for any kind of urls and retrieve the list and also to replace it with foo.

Answer (score 0):

Find one of many [regular expressions for a URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/161738/what-is-the-best-regular-expression-to-check-if-a-string-is-a-valid-url) and use [QString::replace](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qstring.html#replace-16) (the regex overload).

```
QString s;
QRegExp regexp(...);
s.replace(regexp, "foo");
```